# Как узнать формат файла по url, если в url отсутствует расширение?

Tags: php

```
$url ="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=1a521a4c70d04a1a7514963f0e5dfadc-sr&n=13_";
copy($url,"./admin.png");
```

Перед загрузкой файла нужно проверить, что за файл вообще, чтобы ничего лишнего не загружали только изображения различных форматов.

Comment: Никак. Вы либо получаете файл и проверяете его содержимое (единственный надежный способ), либо гадаете на кофейной гуще.

Comment: можно подсмотреть mime тип, который в хедерах возвращается. А можно скачать первые несколько байт (максимум килобайт) и достаточно надежно определить содержимое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип посмотрел через функцию getimagesize, как выше описали в комментариях, параметр mime возвращает тип изображения